# See the time spent on web site since load or the time when page was opened in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, time

Is there a way to tell how much time has passed since the web site has been loaded?
I cannot modify the page, but, what I am hoping for, is some sort of statistic or Chrome debug console command that would tell me time with precision in seconds or worst case - minutes.

EDIT:I need the timer on a single page (`site.com/a.html` and `site.com/b.html` are considered different sites for this purpose). Also, time spent inactive should also be added to timer.

EDIT2: I suppose, exact page load time would work for this purpose too. As in time and date when page was loaded.

Comment: in theory perhaps that could be done in privoxy(which is a web proxy that can rewrite html, so could add code). it may work in some cases, though that'd slow things down pre page coming up, and might be ugly and might not work on all pages unless you got the code placed right for any page like if you figured out  good search and replace function that positioned it just right for any webpage so it always runs the counter code you've written. so, that method of mine doesn't sound that feasible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using Chrome [History page](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95589) for this. It must be noted that I used single tab only. 
Also, I am uncertain of how this would work with Google sync account being used on multiple machines.

Answer (score 1):

The [Time Tracker extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/time-tracker/mokmnbikneoaenmckfmgjgjimphfojkd?hl=en) may do what you want, with minute-level precision.

There's also the [Web Timer extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-timer/ggnjbdfgigejghknieofeahaknkjafim?hl=en) which appears to have second-level precision and a pie chart!

Comment: While solutions you have provided would be a good answer to this question, none of these extensions provide a way to see for how long a single page has been loaded including inactive time. I will clarify the question. Sorry for inconvenience :)

Comment: Ah, I see. I know the dev-tools panel has a timer in it, but you have to manually start it, and I don't think the results are saved anywhere. It might be scriptable, however.